# How do I deal with a violation of sample independence in a Pearson's correlation?

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, assumptions

There was a concern raised by reviewers of a manuscript of mine over the proper execution of a Pearson's correlation. In brief, this was undertaken in order to determine the relationship between the extent of wheel running (y axis) and ethanol intake (x axis) across three, separate 10 day periods in 7 animals.

In the paper, the correlational plots for each 10 day-period had 70 data points: One point for each day and each animal across 10 days of experimentation. The reviewers, however, appropriately pointed out that this is a violation of the assumption of sample independence for Pearson's test, and I should have had only 7 points, which would reflect the means of my two variables for each individual animal across 10 days. Is this appropriate or is there a means of accounting for repeated sampling with a correlation test?

Answer (score 3):

I think this situation calls for either a mixed model (aka multilevel model, hierarchical linear model etc) or a generalized estimating equations approach.

Re the multilevel models: The lm() approach doesn't allow for different slopes in different rats (do rats get better at wheel running? I don't know). This would be PROC MIXED in SAS or lme4() or something similar in R. Both of these also allow you to play with the covariance structure, which the lm() approach does not.

In addition, if you happen to have missing data, multilevel models deal with it better.

Comment: It might help the OP a bit if you commented on how, within a mixed modeling framework, you would get an estimate of correlation that "controls" for the non-independence

Comment: I agree, @marco.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a linear model that predicts wheel running from ethanol intake and rat/mouse id.

In R your data (called `data`) would look something like this

```
Wheel   Eth  RatID
30.2   12.1      1
25.2   10.5      1
...
```

where `RatID` is a `factor`. You then do

```
anova(lm(data))
```

which gives you a couple of numbers, including a test for the slope, which is the relationship between wheel turning and ethanol uptake.

Comment: gui11aume's suggestion might be good too.  Repeated measures ANOVA is a common and accepted technique. You don't directly estimate correlation but the slope does test for the relationship that you are interested in. @guillaume are you doing this with fixed effects or is it a mixed effects model?

Comment: Agreed.  Of course, like you mention @Michael, the lm() isn't going to be the same, and, since there will be error in the x (which ever one I choose...), that's another assumption violation. 

I would go mixed-effects, possibly with lme() and random = RatID.

Comment: @Michael Chernick, the code above is for fixed effect. What is your opinion? Should be mixed effect instead?

Comment: I am always a little confused about that.  When repeated measures are done in SAS using Proc glm the results are different from when they are done usign Proc mixed.  I know that for Proc mixed a covariance structure needs to be specified.  Is that true when useing the repeated option in glm?  I guess Justin knows his data better than I do so if he thinks he needs random effects I would suppose he is right.

Comment: You cannot specify the covariance structure in PROC GLM in SAS. PROC MIXED's REPEATED is used to specify covariance structures for repeated measurements; PROC GLM's REPEATED is used to specify various transformations... with which to conduct (usual) tests. The mixed model approach used in PROC MIXED is more flexible and more widely applicable than either the univariate or multivariate approach. (adapted from the SAS docs for MIXED)

Comment: @PeterFlom Thanks.  I thought something like that was the case. I think your answer is an improvement on gui11ame's suggestion and may be the best solution for Justin.  But I think he wants to show the referee that he can do the inference with his correlation estimate which would lead him to needing the distribution for the correaltion coefficient under dependence and the null hypothesis which is what the bootstrap might be able to allow him to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think that going from $70$ points to $7$ just to force independence is wasteful of the information in the data.  It is not the calculated value of the correlation that is the problem, it is its distribution under the null hypothesis.  Because of repeated testing on the animals the $x$ coordinate for a given animal on one day is correlated with the $x$ coordinate on another day and similarly for the y coordinate so intuitively the variance of the estimate is really higher than what it would be for independent samples of size $n$ ($70$).  But the correlation is not $1$ so the equivalent sample size should be more than $7$.  To give you an idea of what I mean take a look at another problem Suppose I have observations $X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_n$ and I want to estimate the sample mean.  However the sequence is dependent and follows an AR(1) model $X_i = \rho X_{i-1} + \varepsilon_i$, $0<\rho<1$ and the $\varepsilon_i$ are iid. and independent of previous $X_i$s.  Then the sequence is stationary. Let $\sigma^2$ be the variance of the $\varepsilon_i$s and the mean be $0$. Then using stationarity it can be shown that the variance of $X_i$ is  $\sigma^2/(1-\rho^2)$.  Say the  $ε_i$ are Gaussian.  Then $\rho = 0$ is the independent case.  Now in the indpendent case $Var(X_i)=Var(\varepsilon_i)$ = $\sigma^2$ and Var(the sample mean)$=\sigma^2$. Now in principle we can find a larger $n$ so that the variance of the sample mean for the autoregressive sequence is the same as for the independence case.  That defines an equivalent sample size.  Of course this depends on the unknown $\rho$.  But a sample size of 7 in the independent case should not equate to $70$ in the dependent case.  Your problem is complicated.  So I suggest bootstrapping the pairs preserving the order and from that get a bootstrap distribution for your Pearson correlation estimate and base your inference on the bootstrap distribution under the null hypothesis.  Preserving the time dependence is important.  I haven't worked through the details but I think the bootstrap will be consistent or easily modified to be consistent.

Comment: I've done a little bootstrapping from a textbook examples, so I'll try to extrapolate from there... If/when I do, I'll keep this thread posted.